# hosting laravel 4 application in heroku

Tags: php, git, heroku, laravel

I have been receiving this error for quite sometime now. I have a laravel 4 application that I want to host in heroku. I have already created heroku application and now am trying to push my app to heroku using git push heroku master. The following are the results.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\pos>git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 83, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
Writing objects: 100% (60/60), 342.76 KiB | 69.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 60 (delta 40), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> PHP app detected
Build dir is /tmp/build_5b1c5fb6-fa85-4a48-b2a8-127574aeb681
-----> Extracting Apache 2.4.7 PHP 5.5.9 build 2.0-rc1
-----> from http://vulcan-wlian.herokuapp.com/output/e33fbffa-c4ca-4752-8b1c-9ebc49366a1c
Creating Slug Identifier file with id: d325104734915692ee9e8f4189c08e21
Installing Composer binary
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /tmp/build_5b1c5fb6-fa85-4a48-b2a8-127574aeb681/bin/composer.phar
Use it: php bin/composer.phar
Installing Composer dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator dev-master -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator[dev-master].
    - barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator dev-master requires way/generators 1.x -> no matching package found.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for zizaco/entrust dev-master -> satisfiable by zizaco/entrust[dev-master].
    - zizaco/confide 2.0.0.b1 requires laravelbook/ardent 1.1.x -> satisfiable by laravelbook/ardent[v1.1.0].
    - zizaco/confide 2.0.0a1 requires laravelbook/ardent 1.1.x -> satisfiable by laravelbook/ardent[v1.1.0].
    - zizaco/confide 2.0.0b4 requires laravelbook/ardent 2.1.x -> satisfiable by laravelbook/ardent[v2.1.0].
    - zizaco/confide 2.0.0b2 requires laravelbook/ardent 2.1.x -> satisfiable by laravelbook/ardent[v2.1.0].
    - zizaco/confide 2.0.0b3 requires laravelbook/ardent 2.1.x -> satisfiable by laravelbook/ardent[v2.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravelbook/ardent[v1.1.0, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: laravelbook/ardent[dev-master, v1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravelbook/ardent[v2.1.0, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: laravelbook/ardent[dev-master, v2.1.0].
    - zizaco/entrust dev-master requires laravelbook/ardent dev-master -> satisfiable by laravelbook/ardent[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravelbook/ardent dev-master
    - Installation request for zizaco/confide 2.0.x -> satisfiable by zizaco/confide[2.0.0.b1, 2.0.0a1, 2.0.0b2, 2.0.0b3, 2.0.0b4].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app

To git@heroku.com:ckpos.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:ckpos.git'
```

I have don't everything as required but with no success, any idea why?

Comment: I would remove the generators laravel composer  package it has caused me some issue in the past. I think the problem is that latest version of package is requesting a different version of laravel that you have. You should find the version that is on the same laravel version as you. Also are you sure it works on local?

Comment: Whoa! My repo was pushed successfully few days ago and I get the same error today. I now think this is because of a change in the hosted buildpack repo. Please update if you find a solution.

Comment: I found the solution! Posting it now..

Comment: It works fine on my local machine. I think zizaco/confide package causes more problems. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Simply switch back to the older buildpack.
Go to your app directory, where you do `git push heroku master`, and type:

> heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/winglian/heroku-buildpack-php.git#mpm-event-php55-fpm

When I set the buildpack url to the master branch long ago, I had this funny feeling. I should have done this then. Anyways, a lesson learned.

Cheers!

Comment: If you still face problems, try the older buildpack -

heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/winglian/heroku-buildpack-php.git#mpm-event-php-fpm